# How to code beaglebone black to read the data from DHT11 sensor?

Tags: python, beagleboneblack

I am new in using Beaglebone Black. There are libraries to read the data from DHT11 humidity sensor using python in BeagleBone Black. But I can't understand those codings and so i liked to code by myself to read the data by studying the datasheet.

This is the code i used to read the binary 40bit data from DHT11, but i didn't receive properly.

```
import Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO as gpio

import time
data = []
gpio.setup("P8_11", gpio.OUT) 
gpio.output("P8_11", gpio.LOW)    
time.sleep(0.02)    
gpio.output("P8_11", gpio.HIGH)
time.sleep(0.00004)    
gpio.setup("P8_11", gpio.IN)    
for i in range (0,500):    
    data.append(gpio.input("P8_11")
print data    
gpio.cleanup()
```

Comment: *"i didn't receive properly"* - any change of a bit more information there?

Comment: That's unlikely to work from Python in userspace because of all the latency and non-realtime behavior - one-wire protocols are very timing sensitive. You'll have better luck with a kernel driver or a PRU, but you could try it in C in userspace, which will have much less latency than Python.

Comment: can you suggest some tutorial about where to learn C programming for Beaglebone Black?

Comment: Derek Molloy has some great C++ tutorials on his site: http://derekmolloy.ie/